# Getting fields in columns excel sheet

Tags: attachment

I am using the following code to insert a csv attachment on opportunity object.

```
account testacc = new account(name = 'test123acc');
insert testacc;

Opportunity opp = new opportunity(Name=testacc.Name + ' Opportunity ',

                                         StageName='Prospecting',start_date__c = system.today(),End_Date__c=system.today()+45,

                                         CloseDate=System.today().addMonths(3),

                                         AccountId=testacc.Id);
insert opp;
string teststr = string.valueof(opp);
```

Attachment attachment = new Attachment();

```
  attachment.Body = blob.valueof(teststr);

  attachment.Name = String.valueOf('test12345.csv');

  attachment.ParentId = '0064B0000035LlU';

  insert attachment;
```

This is working fine, but in excel sheet am unable to the data column wise (field per column).
I see the excel sheet as following:
[image]

How can I get the data in object in seperate columns for individual fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it worked..!!

```
List<product2> testprd = [select id,name,date__c from product2 where parent_product__c != Null limit 5];
        string header = 'id,name,date \n';
        string finalstr = header ;
        for(product2 prx:testprd){
            system.debug('excel inside:'+prx);
            string recordString = prx.id+','+' " '+prx.name+ ' " '+','+prx.date__c+'\n';
       finalstr = finalstr +recordString;

        }


attachment att = new attachment();
        att.Body = blob.valueof(finalstr);
```